# combine duplicates values in list of dictionaries with a certain key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a huge list of items and I need to find a way to regroup those items that have repeated values. I need to find dictionaries in a series list that have the same `title` and `year`  values, and create a new list for `episode` and `Cast` in which only one dictionary is kept. and if there is no matching i return the dict with list too.

So all dicts which have the same value for name, year should have a single dict and put their different values in a list `cast-list`  and `episode-list` and to **keep also the dict with no duplication.**

I have tried a lot of things, I used two nested for loop, Filter..., but I was not able to do it!

If anyone can help one this, I really appreciate it.

```
[
               {
                    "class": "TV Shows With Five or More Seasons",
                    "location":"usa",
                    "series": [
                        {
                            "title": "Mad Men",
                            "year": "2015",
                            "episode":10,
                            "Cast" :"Elisabeth Moss",   
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Mad Men",
                            "year": "2015",
                            "episode":14,
                            "Cast" :"January Jones",         
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Mad Men vostfr",
                            "year": "2017",
                            "episode":20,
                            "Cast" :"Jon Hamm",
                             "Type" :"Drama"                 
                        }
                    ],
                    "producer": "Matthew Weine",
                }
            ]
```

**I want to group it like this as output:**

```
[
    {
        "class": "TV Shows With Five or More Seasons",
        "location":"usa",
        "series": [
            {
                "title": "Mad Men",
                "year": "2015",
                "episode-list":[10,14],
                "Cast-list" :["Elisabeth Moss","January Jones"],
            },
            {
                "title": "Mad Men vostfr",
                "year": "2017",
                "episode-list":[20],
                "Cast-list" :["Jon Hamm"],
                "Type" :"Drama"           
            }
        ],
        "producer": "Matthew Weine",
    }
]
```

Note: I have to keep the `Type` that exisit in only on dict!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    {
        "class": "TV Shows With Five or More Seasons",
        "location": "usa",
        "series": [
            {
                "title": "Mad Men",
                "year": "2015",
                "episode": 10,
                "Cast": "Elisabeth Moss",
            },
            {
                "title": "Mad Men",
                "year": "2015",
                "episode": 14,
                "Cast": "January Jones",
            },
            {
                "title": "Mad Men vostfr",
                "year": "2017",
                "episode": 20,
                "Cast": "Jon Hamm",
                "Type": "Drama",
            },
        ],
        "producer": "Matthew Weine",
    }
]

for d in lst:
    tmp = {}
    for s in d["series"]:
        tmp.setdefault((s["title"], s["year"]), []).append(s)
    d["series"] = []
    for (title, year), v in tmp.items():
        d["series"].append(
            {
                "title": title,
                "year": year,
                "episode": [s["episode"] for s in v],
                "Cast": [s["Cast"] for s in v],
                "Type": [s["Type"] for s in v if "Type" in s],
            }
        )
        if d["series"][-1]["Type"]:
            d["series"][-1]["Type"] = d["series"][-1]["Type"][0]
        else:
            del d["series"][-1]["Type"]


print(lst)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "class": "TV Shows With Five or More Seasons",
        "location": "usa",
        "series": [
            {
                "title": "Mad Men",
                "year": "2015",
                "episode": [10, 14],
                "Cast": ["Elisabeth Moss", "January Jones"],
            },
            {
                "title": "Mad Men vostfr",
                "year": "2017",
                "episode": [20],
                "Cast": ["Jon Hamm"],
                "Type": "Drama",
            },
        ],
        "producer": "Matthew Weine",
    }
]
```

Comment: thanks @Andrej but this will not work cause i have some null values

Comment: @Learner Do you have json? Try `json.loads()` first then.

Comment: yes i think it will work with json thanks

Comment: I still have a problem with the `Type`